# Why is the console getting stuck on my last function to solve a 9X9 sudoku board in python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, sudoku

I am trying to write some code to solve an easy 9X9 sudoku board in python.
Stuck on the last function: solve(board).

My code:

```
def check1D(A):
    miss = []
    for j in list(range(1,len(A)+1)):
        if j in A:
            continue
        else:
            miss.append(j)
    return(miss)

def check2D(B):
    return(check1D(B.flatten()))

def checkRow(board,x,y):
    return(check1D(board[x,:]))

def checkCol(board,x,y):
    return(check1D(board[:,y]))

def checkBox(board,x,y):
    ymin = (y//3)*3
    xmin = (x//3)*3
    return(check2D(board[xmin:xmin+3,ymin:ymin+3]))
```

The functions above check for a 1D list. The 2D flattens the array to apply the 1D check. Row, col use 1D check to find candadites. Box works out min/max required for the right 3X3 to check for missing numbers using the 2D function.

```
def cand(board,x,y):
    list = []
    box = checkBox(board,x,y)
    row = checkRow(board,x,y)
    col = checkCol(board,x,y)
    for i in box:
        if i in row and i in col:
            list.append(i)
    if len(list) > 1:
        list = [0]
    elif not list:
        list.append(0)
    return(list)

def solve(board):
    while board.min() == 0:
        row = len(board[0,:])
        col = len(board[:,0])
        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(col):
                if board[i][j] == 0:
                    unique = cand(board,i,j)
                    board[i][j] = unique[0]
    return(board)
```

I've checked all my functions and they seem to work. cand(board,x,y) produces a unique candadite or a zero in a list.

The console gets stuck on the B.flatten() method used for a 2D array.

Here is the easy sudoku 9X9 im trying to solve:

```
easy = np.array([
        [0,0,0,  3,7,0,  0,5,6],
        [5,0,0,  0,1,0,  9,7,0],
        [0,6,0,  9,8,0,  3,4,0],

        [0,0,7,  0,0,2,  0,8,0],
        [0,0,9,  0,3,0,  6,0,0],
        [0,5,0,  0,3,0,  6,0,0],

        [0,7,5,  0,6,9,  0,2,0],
        [0,4,8,  0,2,0,  0,0,5],
        [2,9,0,  0,5,8,  0,0,0]
        ])
```

Any help is appreciated. Would like to understand whats wrong with my loops in the last function.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that your solver doesn't work (and hangs) if for all unsolved positions more than one candidate remains. In this case "cand()" always returns `[0]` and no position is newly solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example can't be solved with that method alone. It gets stuck in an endless loop where it can't find any more unique values.

The final board before getting stuck is:

> ```
> [[0, 0, 1,   3, 7, 4,   2, 5, 6],
>  [5, 3, 4,   2, 1, 6,   9, 7, 8],
>  [7, 6, 0,   9, 8, 5,   3, 4, 1],
>
>  [6, 1, 7,   5, 9, 2,   4, 8, 3],
>  [0, 8, 9,   0, 3, 7,   6, 1, 2],
>  [4, 5, 2,   8, 3, 1,   6, 9, 7],
>
>  [3, 7, 5,   1, 6, 9,   8, 2, 4],
>  [1, 4, 8,   7, 2, 3,   0, 6, 5],
>  [2, 9, 6,   4, 5, 8,   0, 3, 0]]
> ```

The data defined in `easy` is invalid with the rules of Sudoku (i.e. Multiple identical values in the same box/row/column, eg. 3 in the centre box).

The rest of this answer uses the below to compensate for this:

```
easy = np.array([
        [0,0,0,  3,7,0,  0,5,6],
        [5,0,0,  0,1,0,  9,7,0],
        [0,6,0,  9,8,0,  3,4,0],

        [0,0,7,  0,0,2,  0,8,0],
        [0,0,9,  0,3,0,  6,0,0],
        [0,5,0,  0,9,0,  7,0,0],

        [0,7,5,  0,6,9,  0,2,0],
        [0,4,8,  0,2,0,  0,0,5],
        [2,9,0,  0,5,8,  0,0,0]
        ])
```

Along with the unique number check in `cand`, you can add in some checks to see if only one value is able to go in that line/column/box:

```
def cand(board,x,y):
    list = []
    box = checkBox(board,x,y)
    row = checkRow(board,x,y)
    col = checkCol(board,x,y)

    if len(box) == 1:
        return box

    if len(row) == 1:
        return row

    if len(col) == 1:
        return col

    for i in box:
        if i in row and i in col:
            list.append(i)
    if len(list) > 1:
        list = [0]
    elif not list:
        list.append(0)
    return(list)
```

This solves the board:

> ```
> [[9, 8, 1,   3, 7, 4,   2, 5, 6],
>  [5, 3, 4,   2, 1, 6,   9, 7, 8],
>  [7, 6, 2,   9, 8, 5,   3, 4, 1],
>
>  [3, 1, 7,   6, 4, 2,   5, 8, 9],
>  [8, 2, 9,   5, 3, 7,   6, 1, 4],
>  [4, 5, 6,   8, 9, 1,   7, 3, 2],
>
>  [1, 7, 5,   4, 6, 9,   8, 2, 3],
>  [6, 4, 8,   7, 2, 3,   1, 9, 5],
>  [2, 9, 3,   1, 5, 8,   4, 6, 7]]
> ```

You should probably also check if the loop in `solve` finishes without having changed any values to handle the program getting stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks :|
Yeah should have checked the board before anything.
Makes sense now.